# Switching between tickbox and input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tickbox and an input field. If user enters something in the field, the tickbox must be uncheck immediately or if user ticks the checkbox, the field must be disabled. How can I do that from client side?

```
    <label for="postcode">Enter the area postcode you want:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="postcode"
           pattern="([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})"
           oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid postcode')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" placeholder="Enter postcode..."><br>
    <label for="nearby">Or</label>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="Nearby" value="">Nearby restaurants</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: "If user enters something in the field, the tickbox must be uncheck immediately"..it has to be checked automatically or unchecked?

Comment: So by default, it has unchecked and the field is empty. But if user enters something in the field, the tickbox must be unchecked even it was checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Add onchange event on checkbox to disable input- check() function
2. Add oninput event to uncheck checkbox - tick() function

```js
    function check(){
      if(document.getElementById('Nearby').checked){
       document.getElementById('postcode').disabled = true
    }else{
      document.getElementById('postcode').disabled = false
    }
    }
    
    function tick(){
      document.getElementById('Nearby').checked = false
    }
```

```html
  <label for="postcode">Enter the area postcode you want:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="postcode"
           pattern="([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})"
           oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid postcode')" oninput="setCustomValidity('');tick()" placeholder="Enter postcode..."><br>
    <label for="nearby">Or</label>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="Nearby" value="" onchange="check()">Nearby restaurants</label>
    </div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqgrrP